# sorting a JTable using getColumnClass() when connected to JDBC

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have spent a few days trying to get my JTable sorting correctly.  I know the code I have to use, but cannot seem to get it for 'fit' and work into my code.  I am getting the TableModel data from a database so if i call the getColumnClass() when initalising the model, I get a NullPointerException (of course), but I can't seem to get the getColumnClass(int) to work anywhere else such as model.getColumnClass(columnIndex).  I only need to sort the first column in numerical order as the rest are strings. Here is my code. (ps: this is the first time using JBDC so I most likely have errors in the order I am calling - or maybe doing it in 'longhand' haha)

```
    public JTable memberList() 
        {
            JTable jTable1;
            DefaultTableModel model;
            model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
            jTable1 = new JTable(model);
            TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(model);

            try 
            {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "select    rm.race_no,cm.firstname,cm.lastname,cm.phone,cm.dob,cm.email,cm.TwinTown_ID,rm.disqualified,cm.notes\n" +
                             "from competitor_master cm join competitor_season cs on cm.competitor_id = cs.competitor_id\n" +
                             "inner join race_master rm on cs.race_no= rm.race_no where cm.twintown_id is not null and cs.season_start_year in (year(sysdate()))\n" +
                             "group by (race_no);";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                String b = "", c = "", d = "", e = "", f = "", g = "", h = "", i = "";
                int a;

                model.addColumn("Member Number");
                model.addColumn("First Name");
                model.addColumn("Last Name");
                model.addColumn("Phone");
                model.addColumn("Date of Birth");
                model.addColumn("Email");
                model.addColumn("TT Member Number");
                model.addColumn("Disqualified");
                model.addColumn("Notes");


                while(rs.next())
                {
                    a = rs.getInt(1);
                    b = rs.getString("FirstName");
                    c = rs.getString("LastName");
                    d = rs.getString("phone");
                    e = rs.getString("dob");
                    f = rs.getString("email");
                    g = rs.getString("TwinTown_ID");
                    h = rs.getString("disqualified");
                    i = rs.getString("notes");
                    model.addRow(new Object[] {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i});
                    model.getColumnClass(1);

                }

                stmt.close();
                rs.close();

            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {

            }

                jTable1.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Microsoft Tai Le", Font.BOLD, 14));
                jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                jTable1.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(234, 168, 82));
                jTable1.getTableHeader().setBorder(null);


            jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);
            return jTable1;

        }
```

```
    public Class getColumnClass (int column){
            if (column==1) {
                return(Integer.class);
            }
            return(String.class);
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to call getColumnClass? Why do you need to recreate the JTable each time you call the method?

Comment: Well, as I said, I'm new to this, but I thought I needed to call the getColumnClass so the the rowSorter knew how to sort the row (numerically - int or alphabetically - string).  I'm not sure why I need to recreate the JTable each time I call the method - I think I'm trying one step at a time, the next is to try the documentListener to dynamically sort the rows on user input.. I have the GUI in a different class (UserInterface) and I have this code in the dataHandler class. so when it is called it is memberTable = dh.memberList(); Sorry, I don't think I'm making much sense :-(

Comment: So, i've taken out any reference to the columnClass and it is sorting but by the first number only. so is sorting like this:
123
17
22
28
45
5
56
66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is sorting but by the first number only. so is sorting like this: 123 17 22 28 45 5 56 66

Because it is treating all data as String data.

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
jTable1 = new JTable(model);
```

You are using the default implementation of the DefaultTableModel and the JTable. The default implementation of the `getColumnClass(...)` method just returns Object.class so the toString() value of each object is sorted.

You don't invoke the getColumnClass() method manually, you need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your `TableModel`:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel()
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass (int column)
    {
        return (column == 0) ? Integer.class : String.class;
    }
};
```